# how can I write/read BigUint64Array to/from a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to encode things from string to BigUint64 and write them to a file for further use.
BigInt cannot be stringified using JSON, so I directly write as BigUint64Array.

However when I would like to read the file and recover BigUint64Array, I received a buffer and problem is that I don't know how to convert the buffer to BigUint64Array

```
const { writeFileSync, readFileSync } = require('node:fs')

const st = new Set([1n, 2n, 3n, 1n, 1n, 1n])
const A = BigUint64Array.from(st)
console.log(A)

writeFileSync('./abc', A)
let x = readFileSync('./abc')
x = BigUint64Array.from(x)
console.log(x)
```

when I try to run this code, I receive

```
node .\test.js
BigUint64Array(3) [ 1n, 2n, 3n ]
R:\mahjong\FYP22070\test.js:9
x = BigUint64Array.from(x)
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot convert 1 to a BigInt
    at Function.from (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (R:\mahjong\FYP22070\test.js:9:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

Answer (score 1):

`writeFileSync` allows you to specify any typed array and writes out its buffer (the bytes of the array) to the file, but what you get back from `readFileSync` is a `Buffer`, and as far as I can tell, there's no *direct* way to convert that buffer's bytes into a `BigUint64Array`. But there's a *very nearly* direct route: Through `Uint8Array`, and using that array's buffer to build the `BigUint64Array` (so we don't make an extra copy of the data):

```
function readBigUint64FromFileSync(fileName) {
    const bytes = Uint8Array.from(readFileSync(fileName));
    return new BigUint64Array(bytes.buffer);
}
```

That doesn't make an *extra* copy for the conversion from `Uint8Array` to `BigUint64Array`, but it does make a copy (the `Buffer` => `Uint8Array`). We can avoid that by seeing how large the file is, allocating a `Uint8Array` of that size, and reading the file into it:

```
function readBigUint64FromFileSync(fileName) {
    const { size } = statSync(fileName);
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(size);
    const handle = openSync(fileName);
    try {
        readSync(handle, bytes);
        return new BigUint64Array(bytes.buffer);
    } finally {
        closeSync(handle);
    }
}
```

If you're doing this in an environment where the file may be actively written by another process, you'll want to implement some kind of guard around that so that we don't see the size of one version of the file but the data of another version of the file. But if not, the above is sufficient.

Complete example:

```
const { writeFileSync, openSync, statSync, readSync, closeSync } = require('node:fs');

function writeBigUint64ToFileSync(array, fileName) {
    writeFileSync(fileName, array);
}

function readBigUint64FromFileSync(fileName) {
    const { size } = statSync(fileName);
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(size);
    const handle = openSync(fileName);
    try {
        readSync(handle, bytes);
        return new BigUint64Array(bytes.buffer);
    } finally {
        closeSync(handle);
    }
}

const st = new Set([1n, 2n, 3n, 1n, 1n, 1n]);
const original = BigUint64Array.from(st);
writeBigUint64ToFileSync(original, "./abc");
console.log(original);

const fromFile = readBigUint64FromFileSync("./abc");
console.log(fromFile);

console.log(`Same? ${original.length === fromFile.length && original.every((n, i) => fromFile[i] === n)}`);
```

*(Or swap in the simpler version of `readBigUint64FromFileSync` if making one copy of the data is okay.)*

Comment: Actually, wait, as I was pressing the post button I just realized we could read directly into the `Uint8Array`'s buffer and avoid making even one copy. It's more complicated, but... I'll update with that.

Comment: Added that option now.

Comment: thanks a lot! it seems cool and let me take some time to digest this method

Comment: omg it works in my program. u r my superman!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your BigInts to string before providing them to `JSON.stringify` something like

```js
const st = new Set([1n, 2n, 3n, 1n, 1n, 1n])
const converted = Array.from(st.values()).map(current => current.toString());
writeFileSync('./abc', JSON.stringify(A));
```

And to convert in the other direction you can just do `BigInt(yourString)` to convert them back to BigInts

Comment: actually my original data are 1.3M strings, each consists of char '1' to '9' and with length 27. for example '1119111121111211911111911', things like that.
and I put all these 1.3M strings into a set and write them into a file later (so that I can try stream with them), so I am wondering whether it would be less time/space consuming if I convert them to bigUint64array or any other typed array? or is it optimal to simply leave them as strings

Comment: @RikaShiro - If you write them as strings, they'll consume more disk space than if you write them as a `BigUint64Array` (since each element of the array takes four bytes, but 27 digits in UTF-8 takes 27 bytes -- 28 if you add a terminator, though you don't necessarily need one). The counterargument is if you write strings (with a terminator), that file is human-readable.